# Request.createResponse returns empty [] and 404 erro how to get comprehensive message

Tags: c#, api, rest, http-status-codes

I am using post man to test our API and if an empty array is returned I would like to get some sort of comprehensive message instead of just blank angle brackets [] and 404 message . Is there a work around for this or at least a helpful property of HttpStatusCode that I can use?

```
if (result.Count > 0)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse<object>(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
else
{
    string[] emptyArray = new string[0];
    return Request.CreateResponse<string[]>(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, emptyArray);
    //return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to use ReasonPhrase to specify reason:

```
   var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent,
        ReasonPhrase = "Empty Result"
    };
```

Comment: I understand the concept but I am having trouble including that in my else clause of the above code to return

Comment: You really need to return string[] allways ?

Comment: Might also use:  return  new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ReasonPhrase = reasonPhrase });